# Why do strings in python 2.7 not have the "__iter__" attribute, but strings in python 3.7 have the "__iter__" attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In both python 2.7 and python 3.7 I am able to do the following:

```
string = "hello world"
for letter in string:
    print(letter)
```

But if I check for the iterable attribute:

python 2.7

```
hasattr(string, "__iter__")
>> False
```

python 3.7

```
hasattr(string, "__iter__")
>> True
```

This is something that I have not found to be documented when making a 2to3 migration, and it has caused a little headache because I have `hasattr(entity, "__iter__")` checks in my code. In python 2.7 this works to differentiate a string from a collection, but not in python 3.7

Really I am asking, what was the design decision, why was it implemented like this. I hope that's not too speculative.

Comment: Try to watch `type(letter)` in both python2 and 3. This will show you the way.

Comment: It looks like they just changed strings from being a special case to using the generic iteration method.

Comment: `str` used the old iteration protocol involving sequential indexing and `__getitem__` until an `IndexError` is thrown. This is still supported, but I believe in the transition from 2 to 3 all built-in containers use the standard iterator protocol. `hasattr(string, "__iter__")` is not really a reasonable way to distinguish strings from other containers, instead, just `isinstance (x, str)`

Comment: Also, it probably the transition wasn't documented because it was never a guarantee and you were unwisely relying on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `str_iterator` class for `str` (run `type(iter("str"))`) was implemented in CPython3. The object of which is returned when called `"str".__iter__()` or `iter("str")`. In CPython2 own iterator' class for `str` wasn't implemented. When you call `iter("str")` you get instance of base iterator class.

See 1 piece of code. `f = t->tp_iter;` - return custom iterator if exist. Otherwise `PySeqIter_New(o)` - return instance of `seqiterobject` structure (see 2 piece of code). As you can see from the 3 piece of code this basic iterator calls `PySequence_GetItem(seq, it->it_index);` on iteration.

If you implement your class that support iteration than you need to define either `__iter__` method or `__getitem__`. If you choose the first option then the returned object must implemented `__iter__` and `__next__` (CPython3) or `next` (CPython2) methods.

**Bad idea to check for `hasattr(entity, "__iter__")`**.

> - If you need to check if the object is iterable, then run `isinstance(entity, Iterable)`.
> - If you need to exclude only `str` then run `isinstance(entity, Iterable) and not isinstance(entity, str)` (CPython3).

### 1

```
PyObject *
PyObject_GetIter(PyObject *o)
{
    PyTypeObject *t = o->ob_type;
    getiterfunc f;

    f = t->tp_iter;
    if (f == NULL) {
         if (PySequence_Check(o)) return PySeqIter_New(o);
         return type_error("'%.200s' object is not iterable", o);
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

### 2

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t it_index;
    PyObject *it_seq; /* Set to NULL when iterator is exhausted */
} seqiterobject;

PyObject *
PySeqIter_New(PyObject *seq)
{
    seqiterobject *it;

    if (!PySequence_Check(seq)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    it = PyObject_GC_New(seqiterobject, &PySeqIter_Type);
    if (it == NULL)
        return NULL;
    it->it_index = 0;
    Py_INCREF(seq);
    it->it_seq = seq;
    _PyObject_GC_TRACK(it);
    return (PyObject *)it;
}
```

### 3

```
static PyObject *
iter_iternext(PyObject *iterator)
{
    seqiterobject *it;
    PyObject *seq;
    PyObject *result;

    assert(PySeqIter_Check(iterator));
    it = (seqiterobject *)iterator;
    seq = it->it_seq;
    if (seq == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (it->it_index == PY_SSIZE_T_MAX) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError, "iter index too large");
        return NULL;
    }

    result = PySequence_GetItem(seq, it->it_index);
    if (result != NULL) {
        it->it_index++;
        return result;
    }
    if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_IndexError) ||
        PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_StopIteration))
    {
        PyErr_Clear();
        it->it_seq = NULL;
        Py_DECREF(seq);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```